# How to check if a value exists in a column selected by header value?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a formula to generate the values in the "Found?" column for the table below.

The value should be "Y" if a given value in the Value column can be found in the column whose header cell corresponds to the value in the Category column (otherwise "N").

I can get it to work with this formula, but ideally, it would be an array formula in C1:

```
=if($A2="","",iferror(if(MATCH($B2,index($D$1:$F,,MATCH($A2,$D$1:$F$1,0)),0),"Y"),"N"))
```

My attempt at an array formula in C1 doesn't work:

```
={"Found?"; ARRAYFORMULA(if($A2:$A="","",iferror(if(MATCH($B2:$B,index($D$1:$F,,MATCH($A2:$A,$D$1:$F$1,0)),0),"Y"),"N")))}
```

| Category | Value | Found? | Colors | Sizes | Flavors |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Colors | Black | Y | Blue | Small | Strawberry |
| Colors | Blue | Y | Red | Medium | Chocolate |
| Colors | Green | Y | Orange | Large | Vanilla |
| Colors | Orange | Y | Yellow | Extra Large | Peach |
| Colors | Pink | N | Green |  | Orange |
| Colors | Red | Y | White |  |  |
| Colors | Violet | N | Black |  |  |
| Colors | White | Y |  |  |  |
| Colors | Yellow | Y |  |  |  |
| Sizes | Extra Large | Y |  |  |  |
| Sizes | Large | Y |  |  |  |
| Sizes | Medium | Y |  |  |  |
| Sizes | Small | Y |  |  |  |
| Flavors | Blueberry | N |  |  |  |
| Flavors | Caramel | N |  |  |  |
| Flavors | Chocolate | Y |  |  |  |
| Flavors | Coconut | N |  |  |  |
| Flavors | Lime | N |  |  |  |
| Flavors | Orange | Y |  |  |  |
| Flavors | Peach | Y |  |  |  |
| Flavors | Pecan | N |  |  |  |
| Flavors | Pineapple | N |  |  |  |
| Flavors | Strawberry | Y |  |  |  |
| Flavors | Vanilla | Y |  |  |  |
| Flavors | Watermelon | N |  |  |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this formula in cell C2:

`=MAP(A2:A,B2:B,LAMBDA(ax,bx,IF(ax="",,IF(REGEXMATCH(bx,TEXTJOIN("|",1,FILTER(D2:F,D1:F1=ax))),"Y","N"))))`

-

[image]

**ALTERNATE FORMULA**

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A),IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B,{INDEX(QUERY({IF(LEN(D2:D),D1&D2:D,);IF(LEN(E2:E),E1&E2:E,);IF(LEN(F2:F),F1&F2:F,)},"Select * Where Col1!=''"))},1,)),"N","Y"),))`

-
[image]

Comment: Cell C1: ={"Found?";MAP(A2:A,B2:B,LAMBDA(ax,bx,IF(ax="",,IF(REGEXMATCH(bx,TEXTJOIN("|",1,FILTER(D2:F,D1:F1=ax))),"Y","N"))))}

Comment: Thanks for this. It looks to work, but it's pretty complicated. Any chance there's a simpler way? I was able to get this formula to work: =if($A2="","",iferror(if(MATCH($B2,index($D$1:$F,,MATCH($A2,$D$1:$F$1,0)),0),"Y"),"N")). But I couldn't make it into a working arrayformula for some reason…

Comment: added alternate array vlookup formula in the answer

Comment: I ended up going with your original formula because it actually has many more columns than just D:F. However, I did find an unexpected behavior. It's returning "Y" for values like "117" if the latter column contains "17". Any way to force an exact value match?

Comment: can you please share sample data replicating this issue for us to check out?!

Comment: I ended up getting it all to work out with this formula: ={"Found?";MAP(A2:A,B2:B,LAMBDA(ax,bx,if(ax="","",iferror(if(match(bx,index($D$2:$F,,match(ax, $D$1:$F$1,0)),0),"Y"),"N"))))}